# react-data-grid - Can you add your own components to the Toolbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toolbar

I am currently using the react-data-grid and I have it almost complete...  I have the filters button showing in the Toolbar.  I need another button to affect all the selected items in the table, and I wanted to add it to the left side of the toolbar, to conserve space.  Does anyone know of a way to do this with the react-data-grid?

I have looked over the code in github, and I see the Toolbar item, which seems to be very specific to the react-data-grid, but there is also the AdvancedToolbar item, and I wasn't sure if that was something that could be used to add your own custom items to the react-data-grid.

There aren't any examples of adding custom buttons or components with the react-data-grid examples, but I was wondering if anyone else has done something like this and could share how you accomplished it.  Thanks.

I tried the suggested solution of using something like the `GroupedColumnPanels` but it doesn't seem to work the same for something like adding generic button objects, like this:

```
const customToolbar = (<Toolbar>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} onClick={this.handleRefresh}>
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" /> Refresh
            </button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} onClick={this.handleReset}>
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" /> Reset Page
            </button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleHideRows}>
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" /> Hide Selected
            </button>
        </Toolbar>);
```

If anyone can help me figure THAT out... I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

You could try extending the Toolbar to add your new functionality, and then override the render method, eg:

```
export class CustomToolbar extends Toolbar {
  onDeleteRow(e) {
    if (this.props.onDeleteRow !== null && this.props.onDeleteRow instanceof Function) {
      this.props.onDeleteRow(e);
    }
  }

  renderDeleteRowButton() {
    if (this.props.onDeleteRow ) {
      return (<button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.onDeleteRow.bind(this)}>
        {this.props.deleteRowButtonText}
    </button>);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="react-grid-Toolbar">
        <div className="tools">
        {this.renderAddRowButton()}
        {this.renderDeleteRowButton()}
        {this.renderToggleFilterButton()}
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

And then your component would be something like:

```
export class MyGridComponent extends React.Comopnent {
  // other code 
  handleDeleteRow(e) {
    console.log("deleting selected rows ", e)
    // handle the deletion
  }
  render() {
    return (<ReactDataGrid
      // other properties
      toolbar={<CustomToolbar onAddRow={this.handleAddRow.bind(this)}
            onDeleteRow={this.handleDeleteRow.bind(this)}
            deleteRowButtonText="Delete Selected"></CustomToolbar>}
    />)
  }
}
```

It looks like the [AdvancedToolbar](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/master/src/addons/toolbars/AdvancedToolbar.js) might be trying to do something like this, but it doesn't inherit the Toolbar's  Add Row or Filter options, and the children are rendered outside the empty toolbar div.

Comment: The solution work great only when you want replace everything inside toolbar in my case I want to add a button beside default filter button of toolbar

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the repo for react data grid add on:

https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/next/packages/react-data-grid-addons/src/toolbars/Toolbar.js

It renders any children you pass to the Toolbar component.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="react-grid-Toolbar">
        <div className="tools">
          {this.renderAddRowButton()}
          {this.renderToggleFilterButton()}
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So you can pass in any buttons you want like this:

```
<Toolbar> <ButtonComponent /></Toolbar>
```

As long as you button has its own self contained state this should work.

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it as done in [Row Grouping Example](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/grouping).

```
var CustomToolbar = React.createClass({
   render() {
     return (<Toolbar>
       <GroupedColumnsPanel groupBy={this.props.groupBy} 
                            onColumnGroupAdded={this.props.onColumnGroupAdded} 
                            onColumnGroupDeleted={this.props.onColumnGroupDeleted}/>
       </Toolbar>);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that out.  I missed that as I don't think I was looking at that specific one.  Appreciate pointing that out though!

Comment: I added more information in the original post, but the above didn't work for something other than the GroupedColumnsPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `flexibleSpaceComponent` prop according to the [docs](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/scheduler/docs/reference/toolbar/#properties)

```js
const ToolbarFlexibleSpace = () => (
  <div>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} onClick={this.handleRefresh}>
      <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" /> Refresh
    </button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} onClick={this.handleReset}>
      <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" /> Reset Page
    </button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleHideRows}>
      <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" /> Hide Selected
    </button>
  </div>
);

const MyToolbar = (
  <Toolbar
    flexibleSpaceComponent={ToolbarFlexibleSpace}
  />
);
```